# Declaring arrays in powershell workflows

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-workflow

I need an array of size n in powershell workflow

```
workflow hai{
   $arr=@(1,2)
   $a=@(0)*$arr.Count #array needed
   for ($iterator=0;$iterator -lt $arr.Count;$iterator+=1){
        $a[$iterator]=$arr[$iterator]
   }
}
```

This shows error at the line

```
$a[$iterator]=$arr[$iterator]
```

We can use like this

```
workflow hai{
   $arr=@(1,2)
   $a=@()
   for ($iterator=0;$iterator -lt $arr.Count;$iterator+=1){
        $a+=$arr[$iterator]
   }
}
```

But my case is different where I have to access the array using index. Is there a way to do this in workflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that error because workflow doesn't support assignment to an indexer.  See this [article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/01/02/powershell-workflows-restrictions.aspx) for a number of limitations of workflow.  Try using an inlinescript to get what you want e.g.:

```
workflow hai{
   $arr = @(1,2)
   $a = inlinescript {
       $tmpArr = $using:arr
       $newArr = @(0)*$tmpArr.Count #array needed
       for ($iterator=0;$iterator -lt $newArr.Count;$iterator+=1){
           $newArr[$iterator] = $tmpArr[$iterator]
       }
       $newArr
   }
   $a
}
```